# Can closed questions be in use again?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Is there a way for a closed question to be open for use again (to be unclosed)? Or what do I have to do for that? And is it ok if a question is closed to be posted a duplicate of it?

Here is the question if I have to do something about it - 
[Rendering two wire-frames in 3DS Max?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36756/is-there-a-way-to-render-an-object-with-double-or-more-wireframes-in-3ds-max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not ok. You should improve your original question not open new questions of the same kind. When your question is good enough it may be reopened. Problem is your posts are duplicates.

PS: Yes you can do what you ask. Not a big MAX guy tough so can not answer you off the shelf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.